# El componente no consigue ver el child en Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, d3.js, viewchild

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un componente de Angular 8.2.2 en el que tengo que mostrar una gráfica con algunos datos.

Dicha gráfica se pinta a través de un wrapper de la librería d3.

Actualmente lo tengo así:

```
<mat-card *ngIf="loaded">
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>Economic balance</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>

        <chart height="420" width="1100" #chart></chart>

    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>


<loader *ngIf="!loaded"></loader>
```

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { InvoiceService } from '../../../services/invoice.service';
import { DateFilter } from '../../../core/date-filter';
import { SignalType } from 'data-model';
import { UtilsTesting } from 'web-resources';
import { ChartData, ChartComponent } from '../../../../public-api';

@Component({
  selector: 'site-economic-balance',
  templateUrl: './site-economic-balance.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class SiteEconomicBalanceComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  private data: ChartData[];
  public loaded: boolean = false;

  @ViewChild('chart', { static: true }) chart: ChartComponent;
  @Input('datefilter') datefilter: DateFilter;

  constructor(private invoiceService: InvoiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  async ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (this.datefilter === undefined || this.datefilter === null) return;

    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() {
    this.invoiceService.getElectricInvoiceEconomicBalance(this.datefilter).subscribe(
      res => {

        const values = res.map(element => ([
          new Date(element.year, element.month, -1),
          element.totalEnergy
        ]));

        this.data = [
          {
            tag: {
              tag: "TAG_01", alarmConfigurations: null, dataSource: null, description: "Tag Signal 01", dynamicFieldValues: null,
              id: 0, isActive: true, isCalculated: false, signalGroups: null, statisticType: null, stringStatisticType: null,
              stringType: null, timeZone: null, type: SignalType.Analog, version: 0
            },
            color: "#FF5733",
            tipo: null,
            dashStyle: null,
            values: UtilsTesting.CreateObjectFromJSON(values)
          }
        ]

        this.chart.init = this.data;

      },
      err => {
        console.log("Error en la obtención del balance económico: ", err);
      }
    )

  }

}
```

Y aquí presento el wrapper:

```html
<div id="container" #container>
    <svg [id]="chartName"></svg>
</div>
```

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AXISORGANIZATION, ChartOptions, CommonChart, Data, Legend, Serie, TOOLTIPCALCULATION, Tooltip, XAxis, YAxis } from 'graphics-d3-wrapper';
import { LocalDatePipe, LocalNumberPipe, PreferencesService } from 'resources';
import { FormatValueHelper } from 'core-signals-lib';
import { ChartData } from '../../core/chart-data';
import { AxisScaleType, Position, VisualizationType } from 'data-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [FormatValueHelper, LocalDatePipe, LocalNumberPipe]
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() height: string;
  @Input() width: string;
  @Input() color: string = "transparent";

  private tags: ChartData[];
  public chartName: string;

  @ViewChild('container', { static: false }) chartContainer: ElementRef;

  constructor(private formatValueHelper: FormatValueHelper, private preferences: PreferencesService, private localNumberPipe: LocalNumberPipe, private localDatePipe: LocalDatePipe) { 
    this.chartName = this.newGuid();
  }

  private newGuid(): string {
    return 'chart_xxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
      var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0,
        v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
      return v.toString(16);
    });
  }

  @Input() set init(data: ChartData[]) {
    this.tags = data;
    this.renderChart();
  }

  private renderChart() {
    const chart = new ChartOptions();
    
    chart.axisOrganization = AXISORGANIZATION.Horizontal;
    chart.backgroundColor = this.color;
    chart.disabledColor = '#CCCCCC';
    chart.color = '#000000';
    chart.gridColor = "rgba(36,40,51,.2)";
    chart.interaction = false;
    chart.interpolationRawEnabled = false;
    chart.mode = 0;
    chart.zoomByWheel = false;

    chart.multilevel = false;
    chart.canvasRendering = false;

    chart.svgName = `#${this.chartName}`;
    chart.heatmap = false;
    chart.heatmapScaleVisible = false;
    chart.stacked = false;
    chart.heatmap = false;

    chart.legend = new Legend();
    chart.legend.enabled = true;
    chart.legend.onItemClick = () => { };
    chart.onPlotClick = () => { }

    chart.tooltip = new Tooltip();
    chart.tooltip.enabled = true;
    chart.tooltip.background = '#FFFFFF';
    chart.tooltip.border = '#CCCCCC';
    chart.tooltip.highlight = true;
    chart.tooltip.decimalNumber = 3;
    chart.tooltip.calculation = TOOLTIPCALCULATION.ByMoment;

    if (this.chartContainer) {
      chart.container = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;
      if (this.width) {
        chart.width = parseInt(this.width, 10);
      } else {
        chart.width = chart.container.offsetWidth;
      }
      if (this.height) {
        chart.height = parseInt(this.height, 10);
      } else {
        chart.height = chart.container.offsetHeight;
      }
    } else {
      throw Error("Chart container was not initialized");
    }

    chart.series = [];

    let minSerie = 0;
    let maxSerie = 0;
    let dataMin = 0;
    let dataMax = 1;
    
    this.tags.forEach(element => {
      let serie = new Serie();

      //Ordenamos los valores por fecha
      element.values.sort(function(a,b){
        return new Date(a[0]).getTime() - new Date(b[0]).getTime();
      });

      //maxSerie=new Date(Math.max.apply(null,element.values)).getTime();
      //minSerie=new Date(Math.min.apply(null,element.values)).getTime();

      const signals = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < element.values.length; i++) {
        if (!isNaN(element.values[i][1])) {
          signals.push(new Data
            (new Date(element.values[i][0]).getTime(), 
            parseInt(element.values[i][1], 10), 
            new Date(element.values[i][0]).getTime(), 
            undefined, 
            undefined, 
            undefined, 
            parseInt(element.values[i][1], 10), 
            undefined, 
            0));
        }

        if(i==0){
          dataMin = parseInt(element.values[i][1], 10);
          minSerie = new Date(element.values[i][0]).getTime();
        }
        if(i == element.values.length-1){
          maxSerie = new Date(element.values[i][0]).getTime();
        }
      }

      serie.data = signals;
      
      const color = (!element.color && element.color === "") ? this.genRGB() : element.color;
      serie.lineColor = color;
      serie.areaColor = color;
      serie.markerColor = color;
      serie.lineWidth = 1;
      serie.opacity = 0.2;
      serie.visible = true;
      serie.title = element.tag.tag;
      serie.decimalNumber = 3;
      serie.markerWidth = 0;
      if(element.dashStyle !=null){
        serie.dashStyle = element.dashStyle;
      }else{
        serie.dashStyle = "Solid";
      }
      if(element.tipo !=null){
        serie.lineType = element.tipo;
      }else{
        serie.lineType = VisualizationType.Area;
      }
      
      
      serie.softened = false;
      serie.customIcon = false;

      serie.signal = element.tag;
      serie.index = 0;
      serie.xAxisIndex = 0;
      serie.yAxisIndex = 0;
      
      /*if ((serie.data.length - 1) > maxSerie) {
        maxSerie = serie.data.length - 1;
      }*/

      signals.forEach((p) => {
        if (p.y > dataMax) {
          dataMax = p.y;
        }
        if (p.y < dataMin) {
          dataMin = p.y;
        }
      });

      chart.series.push(serie);
    });

    //Creación de una Mae en vertical como una serie con 2 puntos con la misma X
    let signalsVertical = [];
    signalsVertical.push(new Data
      (new Date("2023-04-30T21:36:33.801Z").getTime(), 
        dataMin, 
      new Date("2023-04-30T21:36:33.801Z").getTime(), 
      undefined, 
      undefined, 
      undefined, 
      dataMin, 
      undefined, 
      0));
      signalsVertical.push(new Data
        (new Date("2023-04-30T21:36:33.801Z").getTime(), 
          dataMax, 
        new Date("2023-04-30T21:36:33.801Z").getTime(), 
        undefined, 
        undefined, 
        undefined, 
        dataMax, 
        undefined, 
        0));

    
    let serieVertical = new Serie();
    serieVertical.data = signalsVertical;    
    
    const color = this.genRGB();
    serieVertical.lineColor = color;
    serieVertical.lineWidth = 2;
    serieVertical.opacity = 0.2;
    serieVertical.visible = true;
    serieVertical.dashStyle = "Solid";
    serieVertical.title = "MAE_01";
    serieVertical.decimalNumber = 3;
    serieVertical.markerWidth = 2;
    serieVertical.lineType = VisualizationType.Line;
    
    serieVertical.softened = false;
    serieVertical.customIcon = false;

    serieVertical.index = 0;
    serieVertical.xAxisIndex = 0;
    serieVertical.yAxisIndex = 0;

    chart.series.push(serieVertical);
    

    const xAxis = new XAxis();
    xAxis.gridEnabled = false;
    xAxis.min = minSerie;
    xAxis.max = maxSerie;
    xAxis.round = false;
    xAxis.type = AxisScaleType.Temporary;
    xAxis.color = "#000000";
    xAxis.visible = true;

    chart.xAxis = [xAxis];

    const yAxis = new YAxis();
    yAxis.color = "#000000";
    yAxis.visible = true;
    yAxis.min = dataMin;
    yAxis.max = dataMax;
    yAxis.position = Position.Left;
    yAxis.plotLines = [];
    yAxis.round = false;
    yAxis.gridEnabled = true;
    yAxis.type = AxisScaleType.Scalar;
    yAxis.guide = true;

    chart.yAxis = [yAxis];    

    const commonChart = new CommonChart(this.formatValueHelper, this.localDatePipe, this.localNumberPipe, this.preferences);
    commonChart.initChart(chart);

    $("svg").find("rect").css("stroke","transparent");
    $("svg").find(".legendItem0").css("cursor","default");
  }
  
  ngOnInit() { }

  genRGB() {
    return `rgb(${(Math.random()*255).toFixed(0)},${(Math.random()*255).toFixed(0)},${(Math.random()*255).toFixed(0)})`;
  }

}
```

El problema parece ser que no detecta en ningún momento el `ViewChild` ya que `this.chart` siempre es `undefined`. Por tanto, para cuando quiero hacer el `this.chart.init` no puede acceder a la propiedad ya que no se ha renderizado, pero no logro ver el error. En teoría debería poder verlo. He probado a usar promesas, a inicializar el servicio dentro del constructor, a inicializar el `this.chart.init` en el `ngAfterViewInit` pero nada de eso da resultado. Siempre sale el mismo error:

```
core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'init')
    at SafeSubscriber._next (site-economic-balance.component.ts:56:24)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:185:1)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:124:1)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72:1)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35:1)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33:1)
    at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:69:1)
```

¿Por qué podría ser?